# How to get the number of a chosen contact and pass it to an activity

Tags: android

I have created an app that becomes one of the options whenever we are trying to make an outgoing call. (e.g. "Complete action using" (a) dialer (b) skype (c) myApp) I have inserted the CALL_PRIVILEGED intent-filter in order to do that.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml File

```
    <activity android:name=".OutgoingCallActivity">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tel"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here is my OutgoingCallActivity.java

```
...
Intent mIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber) );
    startActivity(mIntent);
...
```

However, I would like to be able to capture the number of the contact that I have chosen and send it to the activity that I have created.

```
String phoneNumber = (get the phone number of the contact that I have selected)
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Intent that you receive when starting the OutgoingCallActivity in the debugger, it has to be in there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get this: 08-17 16:20:45.616: INFO/ActivityManager(2475): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED dat=tel:%2B999999999999 flg=0x10000000 cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity } Now, how can I get this data? dat=tel:%2B999999999999 thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks!!! I finally got it working... :P
String phoneNumber = getIntent().getDataString();

Comment: you can extract phone number using these statements 
  
  String phoneNumber = getIntent().getDataString();
  String[] s=phoneNumber.split(":");
  String ph=Uri.decode(s[1]);